# chrome.identity.getAuthToken and refresh token?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token

I was under the impression that when using chrome.identity.getAuthToken and  gapi.auth.authorize({immediate: true...}); the token would be refreshed in the background.

But it clearly does not... after 40-50 minutes the GMail token expires, the cached one is used but returns 401, as one can expect.

Can a refresh token be received (I know it only comes the first time the access token is received) by using chrome.identity.getAuthToken? It seems to only return the token string in the callback.

Next to the above question, can I retrieve the experation time to check when to re-generate the access token?

This whole Oauth 2 is still harder than I expected it to be.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure the expected response to the 401 is to revoke the auth token, then request another one.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-removeCachedAuthToken

chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken({token: }, function callback)

Comment: It turned out that the token indeed was refreshed nice and clean when calling getAuthtoken again, there seems to be no need to remove it from the tokenCache. The problem was that I needed to call gapi.auth.authorize again as well... now it works fine. Still a bit unsure it is the correct way though.

Comment: @ShadowHunter When you call getAuthToken() again, does it give you a new refresh_token as well, or just a new access/bearer token?

Comment: @ShadowHunter when I try to use gapi.auth.authorize irrespective of the immediate flag in the background script of my chrome extension. I get the error about external visibility, invalid cookie. How did you work around that?